# increase and decrease S_POST variable using ajax

Tags: php

```
$(".into, .out").click(function(){
var which = $(this).attr("class");
alert (which);  // `into` or `out` depending what is clicked
var b = $(this).siblings().children(".count").html();  // starting value is `0`
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {which:which, b:b},
        context: this,
        success: function(data) {
            alert (data);  // 1, 2, 3...
        }
    });
});
```

process.php

```
if ($_POST["which"] = "into") {
$_POST["b"] ++;
}
else{
$_POST["b"] --;
}

echo json_encode($_POST["b"]);
```

I expect the final result to be increased if `into` is clicked and decreased if `out` is clicked. But it is always increased, never decreased !

Comment: It doesn't make sense to reassign to `$_POST` and is questionable practice.. use a separate variable.

Comment: @user2864740, WHY it doesn't make sense? WHY is questionable practice? Variable is variable, isn't it ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because it is an "input". It is questionable because it is confuses the "input" with the data and how it is processed *from* the "input".

Comment: @user2864740, where do you see `input` tag in my post? It is not an input, but content of a div.

Comment: https://www.google.com/?&q=define%20input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need check condition not to assign value

```
if ($_POST["which"] == "into") {
```